# How to create timeseries for two property?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, time-series

I have a car model that represents a specific car. I want collect the buy price by time.

But I can't get how config it using typescript

```
export type Car = {
    _id: string;
    // props
    code: string;
    buyPrice?: number;
    buyPriceDate?: Date;
};

// schema
const CarSchema = new Schema<Car>(
    {
        // props
        code: { type: String, required: true },
        buyPrice: { type: Number, required: false },
        buyPriceDate: { type: Date, required: false },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    },
);

export default model('Car', CarSchema);
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: the timeseries is a feature of mongo. when we can have property where you can set new value, but engine generate new record. I can't find how configure it via scheme